# Why aren't there any man pages for disown or other Ubuntu commands?

Tags: command-line, manpage

```
phatez@phatez-laptop:~$ help

GNU bash, version 4.3.46(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
These shell commands are defined internally.  Type `help' to see this list.
Type `help name' to find out more about the function `name'.
Use `info bash' to find out more about the shell in general.
Use `man -k' or `info' to find out more about commands not in this list.

A star (*) next to a name means that the command is disabled.

 job_spec [&]                                             history [-c] [-d offset] [n] or history -anrw [filena>
 (( expression ))                                         if COMMANDS; then COMMANDS; [ elif COMMANDS; then COM>
 . filename [arguments]                                   jobs [-lnprs] [jobspec ...] or jobs -x command [args]>
 :                                                        kill [-s sigspec | -n signum | -sigspec] pid | jobspe>
 [ arg... ]                                               let arg [arg ...]
 [[ expression ]]                                         local [option] name[=value] ...
 alias [-p] [name[=value] ... ]                           logout [n]
 bg [job_spec ...]                                        mapfile [-n count] [-O origin] [-s count] [-t] [-u fd>
 bind [-lpsvPSVX] [-m keymap] [-f filename] [-q name] [>  popd [-n] [+N | -N]
 break [n]                                                printf [-v var] format [arguments]
 builtin [shell-builtin [arg ...]]                        pushd [-n] [+N | -N | dir]
 caller [expr]                                            pwd [-LP]
 case WORD in [PATTERN [| PATTERN]...) COMMANDS ;;]... >  read [-ers] [-a array] [-d delim] [-i text] [-n nchar>
 cd [-L|[-P [-e]] [-@]] [dir]                             readarray [-n count] [-O origin] [-s count] [-t] [-u >
 command [-pVv] command [arg ...]                         readonly [-aAf] [name[=value] ...] or readonly -p
 compgen [-abcdefgjksuv] [-o option]  [-A action] [-G g>  return [n]
 complete [-abcdefgjksuv] [-pr] [-DE] [-o option] [-A a>  select NAME [in WORDS ... ;] do COMMANDS; done
 compopt [-o|+o option] [-DE] [name ...]                  set [-abefhkmnptuvxBCHP] [-o option-name] [--] [arg .>
 continue [n]                                             shift [n]
 coproc [NAME] command [redirections]                     shopt [-pqsu] [-o] [optname ...]
 declare [-aAfFgilnrtux] [-p] [name[=value] ...]          source filename [arguments]
 dirs [-clpv] [+N] [-N]                                   suspend [-f]
 disown [-h] [-ar] [jobspec ...]                          test [expr]
 echo [-neE] [arg ...]                                    time [-p] pipeline
 enable [-a] [-dnps] [-f filename] [name ...]             times
 eval [arg ...]                                           trap [-lp] [[arg] signal_spec ...]
 exec [-cl] [-a name] [command [arguments ...]] [redire>  true
 exit [n]                                                 type [-afptP] name [name ...]
 export [-fn] [name[=value] ...] or export -p             typeset [-aAfFgilrtux] [-p] name[=value] ...
 false                                                    ulimit [-SHabcdefilmnpqrstuvxT] [limit]
 fc [-e ename] [-lnr] [first] [last] or fc -s [pat=rep]>  umask [-p] [-S] [mode]
 fg [job_spec]                                            unalias [-a] name [name ...]
 for NAME [in WORDS ... ] ; do COMMANDS; done             unset [-f] [-v] [-n] [name ...]
 for (( exp1; exp2; exp3 )); do COMMANDS; done            until COMMANDS; do COMMANDS; done
 function name { COMMANDS ; } or name () { COMMANDS ; }>   variables - Names and meanings of some shell variable>
 getopts optstring name [arg]                             wait [-n] [id ...]
 hash [-lr] [-p pathname] [-dt] [name ...]                while COMMANDS; do COMMANDS; done
 help [-dms] [pattern ...]                                { COMMANDS ; }


phatez@phatez-laptop:~$ man ulimit


phatez@phatez-laptop:~$ man disown

No manual entry for disown


phatez@phatez-laptop:~$
```

Comment: http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash see SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS (all caps are from the source, I just pasted)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`disown` is a bash built in. So `man bash` will show ...

> disown [-ar] [-h] [jobspec ...]
>
> Without  options,  remove  each jobspec from the table of active
>                 jobs.  If jobspec is not present, and neither the -a nor the  -r
>                 option  is  supplied, the current job is used.  If the -h option
>                 is given, each jobspec is not removed from  the  table,  but  is
>                 marked  so  that  SIGHUP  is  not  sent  to the job if the shell
>                 receives a SIGHUP.  If no jobspec is  supplied,  the  -a  option
>                 means  to  remove or mark all jobs; the -r option without a job‐
>                 spec argument restricts operation to running jobs.   The  return
>                 value is 0 unless a jobspec does not specify a valid job.

There are plenty more of those. [Here is a list](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Job-Control-Builtins.html).

To list the help type

```
help disown
```

> or other ubuntu commands?

ALL Ubuntu (linux is more precise) commands have a manual page.

---

`ulimit` does have a manual page.

> ULIMIT(3)                  Linux Programmer's Manual                 ULIMIT(3)
>
> NAME       ulimit - get and set user limits
>
> SYNOPSIS
>
> ```
>   #include <ulimit.h>
>
>   long ulimit(int cmd, long newlimit);
> ```

But you probably meant the *[parameter](http://tldp.org/LDP/solrhe/Securing-Optimizing-Linux-RH-Edition-v1.3/x4733.html)*?

2 ways:

```
$help ulimit
ulimit: ulimit [-SHabcdefilmnpqrstuvxT] [limit]
    Modify shell resource limits.

    Provides control over the resources available to the shell and processes
    it creates, on systems that allow such control.

    Options:
      -S    use the `soft' resource limit
      -H    use the `hard' resource limit
      -a    all current limits are reported
      -b    the socket buffer size
      -c    the maximum size of core files created

 ...

$ ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 46690
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 46690
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Comment: The `ulimit(3)` man manpage is about the C function not the command line program.

Comment: @FlorianDiesch I know I know. Was still working on it :D Was typing it when I saw you edit the question (and then saw he actually knew it was about the parameter ;) )

Comment: You can use `type` to find out whether any given command is a builtin, a function, an alias or an executable file. `type disown` will tell you that disown is a shell builtin.

Comment: @FlorianDiesch: That's what the little "(3)" after the name means. Section 3 is the C library section, section 2 is for system calls, and section 1 is for commands.

Answer (score 12):

When you type `help` you see the commands that are built in bash. To see help for these commands type `help <command>`:

```
help ulimit
help disown
```

When you use `man` (short for manual), you display help for binary programs that are not part of bash. You noticed that you get the help for `ulimit` if you type `man ulimit`. However, the manual for ulimit is not for the bash command. When you type `man ulimit` you get the manual for the C programming header file `ulimit.h`, which is something completely different.

Answer (score 2):

`ulimit` and `disown` are Bash built in functions and those don't have a manpage of its own but are described in the Bash manpage.

If you are running bash you can use the `help` command, e.g.:

```
$ help disown
```

You may want to pipe the output into `less` so you can scroll and search, e.g.

```
$ help disown | less
```

Answer (score 1):

When in doubt about whether a command is a Bash builtin, an executable file, both, or something else:

```
$ type -a kill
kill is aliased to `echo 'You should not use kill - use OUPMclient -K instead.';'
kill is a shell builtin
kill is /usr/bin/kill
kill is /bin/kill
```

This is an peculiar example, since our provider wants us to use some other command rather than `kill` for their application's processes.